# Batch file to move first document from a folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to create a batch file which should move the first document from the provided source location to another location.

Consider that the source folder has 10 files I just want to move any one file from 10 to another path. I also need to store the moved file name in a temporary variable.
I tried using move command as below

```
MOVE "C:\temporaryfolder\*.txt" "C:\Backup"
```

But I am getting an error called as multiple files cannot be copied to single files.

Please help in this case.

Comment: @shree.pat18 - The command only works if a folder named "C:\Backup" exists, in which case it moves all files. Otherwise it assumes the target is a file name, and gives the "Cannot move multiple files to a single file." error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming "C:\Backup" represents a folder, and not a file. The folder must exist before you can move files to it. You will get your reported error if the target folder does not yet exist.

Also, you cannot restrict the MOVE command to move only one file if the source mask matches multiple files. The solution is to use a FOR loop with code that limits the number of MOVEs. I use a GOTO to break out after the first move, or you can use IF DEFINED as Magoo has done to limit the number of actions taken.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "source=C:\temporaryfolder"
set "target=C:\Backup"
if not exist "%target%\" md "%target%"
for %%F in ("%source%\*.txt") do (
  set "file=%%~nxF"
  move "%%F" "%target%" >nul
  goto :break
)
:break
echo File "%file%" was moved from "%source%" to "%target%"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set var=""&for %a in (c:\temp\*.txt) do if not defined var set "var=%a"&move "c:\temp\%a" "c:\backup\"
```

as a command direct from the prompt.

To use as a batch file line, change each `%` to `%%`.

filename-moved appears in variable `%var%`

Comment: +1, I'm not sure if the OP wants the full path stored in the variable, or just the file name.